# system windows forms timer parameters

Tags: c#, .net, timer

How can you pass the parameter to a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`?

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer;
timer.Interval = 1000;
timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
timer.start

private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

How can I pass the value of the object `sender`?

Comment: What do you want to achieve, the sender is the **Forms.Timer** and it will be called as per the interval set

Comment: use Tag property of your timer as userState  --- check the updated answer

Answer (score 6):

Simple timer code - there is no need to pass any sender its get call when interval time ends.

```
    Timer t = new Timer();

    t.Interval = 2000;

    timer1.Enabled = true;

    timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(OnTimerEvent);

//You can use Tag property of your timer as userState

    void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Timer timer = (Timer)sender;
        MyState state = timer.Tag  as MyState;
        int x = state.Value;
    }
```

have look to this for detail : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/WorkingwithTimerControlinCSharp11302005054911AM/WorkingwithTimerControlinCSharp.aspx

Comment: but i want to pass the database row into timer

Comment: the Tag property is of type object so you can just do `t.Tag = myDatarow` and in the `time1_Tick()` eventhandler you can read it out as `DataRow row = timer.Tag as DataRow;` if you follow the code from Pranay Rana's answer

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is a **Tag** property on timer class.